# How to diagnose a difficult to pin down crash when using a line edit?

Tags: qt, crash

My Qt desktop application - which can be thought of as a log viewer - has reports from users of it crashing when the log search field is used. The issue is really difficult to pin down however.

Is it possible to automate reproduction of this similar to fuzzing technies? Are there any macro test tools that could be used?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Yes, something like http://pastebin.com/fTnNqeQD

Comment: If you can't reproduce it yourself, it's going to be tricky. My two guess are a memory overwrite that's corrupted the QLineEdit instance data, or the instance has been destroyed in the middle of a paint operation. If the issue is a memory overwrite and you're running on Linux, valgrind is enormously helpful.

Comment: Don't think any instances should be getting destroyed. I was hoping to be able to replicate the crash by having the application run often and having _something_ simulate the user typing into it every once in a while - is there such something I can use?

Comment: Try valgrind. It'll often point to the problem even before the interaction happens (if the cause of the crash is in the initialization code).